# Set ng-model value to button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have this little snippet of code to set the `root.lowWeight` and `root.highWeight` to my controller.

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter Low Range..." class="form-control input-xs">
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter High Range..." class="form-control input-xs">
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="assignWeights()">Select Model</button>
```

Controller model:

```
//set the initial root scope to empty object
$scope.root = {};
//define root weight
$scope.root.lowWeight = 0;
$scope.root.highWeight = 0;
```

I know I could just use `ng-model="root.lowWeight"` to set the value, but ng-model triggers on element `input` event.

How can I either:

a) Send the input values in via `assignWeights(param1, param2)`

b) Change ng-model to trigger input on button click (seems hacky, less preferred solution)

I also know I could use JS/jQuery to trigger the input event and block the input event, but that's a last ditch effort I will 99.9% not do.

Comment: not sure I understand correctly, but maybe you seek this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, can't you just use ng-model, then the function assigns values to the model values?

Comment: @NitsanBaleli that's close, I could do `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"` and the button click will "act" like a click event, but I'd like to have it purely assigned to the button.

Comment: @Sam as I said, the `ng-model` is bound to the input event, so while it would work, it would not be bound to the button click. I need to have it assigned to the model when the button is clicked

Comment: one solution would be to assign it to the model under a different name - inputData.lowWeight, then function $scope.root.lowWeight = $scope.inputData.lowWeight on button click

Comment: @Sam that's not a bad method! Is there a way to access an input element scope inside the form? I'm trying the temp values now.

Comment: Great. I have given an example plunkr in my answer which I think answers your question - yes it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using seperate scope object: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oi6IXqyMtjvHDqD2xwm7?p=preview)

Html:

```
Low: <input type="text" name="lowRange" ng-model="inputData.lowWeight">
High: <input type="text" name="highRange" ng-model="inputData.highWeight">
```

Js:

```
 $scope.assignWeights = function() {
        $scope.lowWeight = $scope.inputData.lowWeight;
        $scope.highWeight = $scope.inputData.highWeight
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your assignWeights function, you could use a selector to retrieve the values of the inputs and then assign your scope variable values based on that. Just assign a name to each input.

E.g.

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter Low Range..." class="form-control input-xs" name="lowRange">
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter High Range..." class="form-control input-xs" name="highRange">
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="assignWeights()">Select Model</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.assignWeights = function() {
    $scope.root.lowWeight = document.querySelector('input[name="lowRange"]').value
    $scope.root.highWeight = document.querySelect('input[name="highRange"]').value
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lm8GFA0CD0zWwgAMSLah?p=preview

Comment: While this might work, it is not the "angular way" that I need to achieve. Thank you, though.